# Prepend and append a string to each element of $* in shell

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

I'm looking for the simplest solution that takes `$*` as input, and expands to each element prefixed and suffixed with a given string:

```
$*=foo bar baz
<solution(x,y)>=xfooy xbary xbazy
```

I can do either prepending or appending, but not both:

```
echo ${*/#/x}
# prints xfoo xbar xbaz
```

```
echo ${*/%/y}
# prints fooy bary bazy
```

I'm unable to combine the two solutions. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) claims the value returned by the expansion in the parameter=* case is a list, but I'm unable to use it as such. I want to pass the resulting array of values to a further command as separate arugments, therefore simply building a single string wouldn't work.

Comment: The last paragraph of Stephane's answer is important. `$*` is almost certainly not what you want to be using; `"$@"` is the right thing when you want to deal with the argument list _as a list of separate strings_ instead of converting it to a single string.

Comment: Did you intend a solution for shells in general, or for bash? If bash, consider using the bash tag.

Comment: @kojiro: I'm going to use it in a specific shell context (either bash, zsh or ksh), but I'm also interested in a POSIX standard solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo $*
FIELDS=("${@/#/x}")
FIELDS=("${FIELDS[@]/%/y}")
echo "${FIELDS[*]}"
```

When run:

```
$ t.sh foo bar baz
foo bar baz
xfooy xbary xbazy
```

Comment: Note that `${var/pattern/replacement}` is not a `sh` operator. I'd advise against giving a `sh` extension to a script which uses  it. You'd also need to make sure the script is interpreted by a shell that supports it (ksh93, where it comes from or zsh/mksh/bash) by using the corresponding `#! /path/to/shell -` she-bang.

Comment: To emphasize that -- while many folks _do_ use `.sh` extensions on non-POSIX shells, this is frowned on in the bash community. See the history of the relevant factoid from the freenode #bash IRC bot: http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh; to quote its current content here: "Don't use extensions for your scripts. Scripts define new commands that you can run, and commands are generally not given extensions. Do you run `ls.elf`? Also: bash scripts are *not* sh scripts (so don't use .sh) and the extension will only cause dependencies headaches if the script gets rewritten in another language."

Comment: ...it's the same as how a Python *library* gets a `.py` extension, but a Python *executable* has no extension at all (you run `pip`, not `pip.py`). A shell script should have an extension if it's intended to be sourced ("dotted") into an existing interpreter, but not if it's intended to be invoked as an executable. See also the essay at http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful

Comment: Good info, thanks. FWIW, I'd also advise against naming a script "t" as well.

Answer (score 11):

`${var/pattern/replacement}` is a ksh93 parameter expansion operator, also supported by `zsh`, `mksh`, and `bash`, though with variations (`mksh`'s currently can't operate on arrays).

### ksh93

In `ksh93`, you'd do `${var/*/x\0y}` to prefix the expansion of `$var` with `x` and suffix with `y`, and `${array[@]/*/x\0y}` to do that for each element of the array.

So, for the array of positional parameters:

```
print -r -- "${@/*/x\0y}"
```

(beware however that like for your `${*/#/x}`, it's buggy when the list of positional parameters is empty).

### zsh

`zsh`'s equivalent of `ksh93`'s `\0` to recall the matched string in the replacement is `$MATCH`, but only if you use `(#m)` in the pattern (for which you need the `extendedglob` option):

```
set -o extendedglob
print -r -- "${@/(#m)*/x${MATCH}y}"
```

But in `zsh`, you can nest parameter expansions, so you can also do:

```
print -r -- ${${@/#/x}/%/y}
```

Though you would probably rather use the `$^array` operator which turns on `rcexpandparam` for the expansion of that array, making it behave like brace expansion:

```
print -r -- x$^@y
```

Or you could use:

```
printf -v argv x%sy "$@"
```

To modify `$@` (aka `$argv` in `zsh`) in-place (here assuming `"$@"` is not the *empty list*).

### bash

In the `bash` shell, you'd probably need to do it in two steps with an intermediary array as [shown by @L.ScottJohnson](/a/599775), or modifying `$@` in place with:

```
set -- "${@/#/x}"
echo -E "${@/%/y}"
```

(here assuming the prefix (`x` in this case), doesn't start with `-`).

### POSIXly

You could modify the positional parameters in-place with a loop:

```
for i do
  set -- "$@" "x${i}y"
  shift
done
echo "$@"
```

(though beware that `echo` can't be used portably to display arbitrary data that may contain backslash characters or start with `-`)

### Note

Note that the `$*` form of parameter expansion (which is only useful quoted), is the one that is meant to *concatenate* the positional parameters (with the first character of `$IFS`, SPC by default). You need `$@` (again, quoted) to expand to all positional parameters as separated arguments. Unquoted, `$*` and `$@` make little sense (except in `zsh` where they expand to the non-empty positional parameters) as they would be subject to split+glob, and the behaviour varies between shells.

Answer (score 3):

Given a list in `$@`
... print it

```sh
set -- foo bar baz
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

```
foo
bar
baz
```

... perform a list op

```sh
set -- $(printf 'x%sy ' "$@")
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

```
xfooy
xbary
xbazy
```

... stringify list

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$*"
```

```
xfooy xbary xbazy
```

No special bash features involved.

Comment: But you're using the split+glob operator, which means that won't work if the elements of the original list contain characters of `$IFS` or wildcard characters (try after `set -- 'a b' '*'` in a directory that contains a `xutils.py` file for instance).

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution, but unfortunately `set -- $(printf 'x%sy ' "$@")` does not and cannot work reliably because of [quoting and $IFS splitting problems](https://superuser.com/a/1529316/127149). You need to use a `for` loop to be sure you are taking 1 arg input and transforming it into 1 arg output. Try `set -- 'a b' 'p" "q'` and try to convert that to 2 args `xa by` and `xp" "qy` and you will see.